# Change to a Different Colour For Each Bootstrap Active Tab (CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can successfully change the colour of the active tab and non active tabs as a group, but is it possible to do so for each individual tab?

I'm trying to accomplish a different background colour and white text for active tabs and non active tabs to have a white background but different text colour.

Here is the current working code:

```
 .nav-tabs > li > a {
    background-color: #7f7fff !important;
}

 .nav-tabs > li > a:hover{
  background-color: #cc0033 !important;
    color:#fff !important;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  background-color: #cc0033 !important;
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

**html**

```
                      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#start">start </a></li>
                      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">menu1</a></li>
                      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">menu2</a></li>
```

**EDIT**
I have now added a class to the 'a' tag as suggested by Charlie below and still cannot get the colour to change to specific tabs

```
.menu1TabCs > li.active > a, .menu1TabCs .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .menu1TabCs .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  background-color: orange !important;
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Use [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) probably something like `.active:nth-child(1)` (select first one) and so on.

Comment: also you aren't restricted to using only one class on an element and you have no classes on the `<a>` so is pretty simple to add them

Comment: @charlietfl ahhh I see, im attempting this now, would you use the same css? I cant get it to work with the classes either using the same code but with the class name before

Comment: then your rules aren't specific enough or selectors are wrong. Suggest reading up on how css selector specificity works. You can also see which rules out rank others on any element in page using browser dev tools dom inspector

Comment: appears you are putting class on wrong element or creating selector backwards...don't you want the `<a>` to change? Not the whole group?

Comment: im just using the class name now i.e. menu1TabCs.active {} and starting to get somewhere, I hope. Thanks for your input btw, very helpful @charlietfl

Comment: Could also be I've misinterpreted what expectations are also. I had interpreted different colors for different tabs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `nth-child()` to target the appropriate `<li> ... </li>` element.

```css
.nav-tabs > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #141414;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: orange;
}
.nav-tabs > li:nth-child(2) > a {
  color: blue;
}
.nav-tabs > li:nth-child(3) > a {
  color: green;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  background-color: #7f7fff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li > a:focus,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  background-color: #cc0033;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#start">start </a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">menu1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">menu2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```